# Microsoft Graph Search returning duplicates

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search

I am querying `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query` with the following payload:

```
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": [
                "listItem"
            ],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "uniqueid:925211fd-fc7e-4ed8-95fb-0bd00f378e8b"
            },
            "trimDuplicates": true,
            "fields": [
                "uniqueid",
                "originalpath"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Searching for UniqueID I would expect a single result, but instead I get the same item twice:

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "searchTerms": [],
            "hitsContainers": [
                {
                    "hits": [
                        {
                            "hitId": "925211fd-fc7e-4ed8-95fb-0bd00f378e8b",
                            "rank": 1,
                            "summary": "",
                            "resource": {
                                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.listItem",
                                "fields": {
                                    "uniqueid": "{925211fd-fc7e-4ed8-95fb-0bd00f378e8b}",
                                    "originalpath": "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/POC/POC Docs/Employee Contracts/JohnD Employee Contract.docx"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "hitId": "925211fd-fc7e-4ed8-95fb-0bd00f378e8b",
                            "rank": 2,
                            "summary": "",
                            "resource": {
                                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.listItem",
                                "fields": {
                                    "uniqueid": "{925211fd-fc7e-4ed8-95fb-0bd00f378e8b}",
                                    "originalpath": "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/POC/POC Docs/Employee Contracts/JohnD Employee Contract.docx"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "total": 2,
                    "moreResultsAvailable": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.searchResponse)"
}
```

I get duplicate results with other queries as well. It is not limited to a specific file or site. If I do the same search directly against SharePoint search I only get a single result as expected.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

Edit:

After digging in the SharePoint home search (which also uses graph and gives me multiple results), I found an interesting detail indicating that the duplicate item comes from OneDrive. My hypothesis is that when I edit an item and it is put in "Recent" in OneDrive, the item is then returned by Graph. But I have not yet found a way to filter out these since they "look" identical. My solution for now is to simply filter out duplicate items before using the result.

Edit 2:

After 6 months dealing with various support instances I was finally able to contact MS Graph support by submitting a request in Azure Portal (instead of M365 support). They sort of acknowledged the problem. The problem was then partially fixed, however if i added paging to the request with more than 50 items per request the problem remained. After reporting this too, a bit later everything now appears to work.

Comment: I would expect that searching for UniqueID will always return one result no matter if trimDuplicates is true or false. Do you share the file with other users? It seems to me like a bug

Comment: No, no sharing. I should add that it's not only this specific file.

Comment: After contacting MS support, and being sent to three different departments, they concluded that they cannot help me and directed me to contact one of their Graph development partners and helped me write a letter to them. This partner never returned to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By contacting Microsoft Graph support via Azure Portal the issue was eventually fixed silently. I can only conclude that this was an issue in MS Graph.

Answer (score 0):

per my test, unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your issue. In my tests, I can use the following Graph API well and return only one result:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query
```

My test result:
[image]

I suggest you can create a **feedback** on this issue, more professional will help you. Thank you for your understanding.

**Feedback:** https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ebe2edae-97d1-ec11-a7b5-0022481f3c80

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the problem when I add "sortProperties"

Has duplicates:

```
{
    "requests": [{
            "entityTypes": ["driveItem"],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "<UNIQUE ID HERE>"
            },
            "fields": ["id", "name", "uniqueId"],
            "trimDuplicates": true,
            "sortProperties": [{
                    "name": "FileName",
                    "isDescending": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Does not have duplicates:

```
{
    "requests": [{
            "entityTypes": ["driveItem"],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "<UNIQUE ID HERE>"
            },
            "fields": ["id", "name", "uniqueId"],
            "trimDuplicates": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Unfortunately it seems I have to choose between unsorted or duplicated results.